# Wrong size shown in network tab of firefox developer tools for redirects (302 and 301)

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

I'm having this situation where image requests are made to an `image` endpoint, passing in reference and width as arguments and the server returns a 302 redirect to the image resource. At the moment that 302 triggers a 301 to another domain, and then after 2 redirects the image is loaded. The image filesize is 18KB.

Now the "problem"/question I have is when looking at firefox debugger tools (network tab) for this 3 requests, I see that it is showing me that 3 times 18KB were transferred, but the redirects should be much much smaller (range of 100B-300B).

the screen shot of the firefox network tab
[image]

Is this a bug in the firefox developer tools or am I missing some concept here and the browser actually downloads so much for every image?

Looking at the same page in the chrome developer tools, I see something more like what I would expect:
[image]

And then I ran the same request also using ARC and the response(s) I see there are shown on the next image (and also get the responses along the same lines using curl).[image]

I'm using firefox 62.0.2 (64 bit) browser and chrome 68.0.3440.106.

Any ideas?

Comment: I came here for the very same question, and I think it is a bug in the debugger since I have it in a very different context

Comment: I've posted the question on the firefox forums as well and also on bugzilla there is a ticket open at the moment, but don't have any more information yet.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1484781

Comment: The bug is still there, not only does it show wrong size but it shows the result of the redirect as own Response too.

Latest comment I found: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1617852#c5